# Product pages were found as duplicate content and thin content

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, ecommerce, products, thin-content

I have a lot of products on my website that only have a short description on them, and don't have much content.
Google does not show them in the index when I search for my domain and says:

"In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 428 already displayed."

What can I do to solve this issue? Do I have to create content for every single product page?

Is there something I can do in "Google Analytics" and "Google Console" about this?

My competitor's product pages don't have any content but they have good ranking in Google page results. How come?

Comment: Duplicate entries in the SERPs are due to duplicate content. To avoid this, you will need unique content that allows your pages to stand alone. You must provide content that stands out. Once this is done, it will take a while for the metrics to accumulate before your content can be seen as superior, providing that it is, and be selected to appear. Your content has to be seen as more valuable than the rest. This takes time. Cheers!!

Comment: you suggest that i have to build unique content for every single product page? @closetnoc

Comment: I realize this may not be something you are prepared to do. I am, however, telling you search works and what is required to prevent getting lost into the search abyss. Otherwise, advertising may be your other option. Your ad could be seen even if your SERP link will not.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how big or small is your competitor website in relation to yours, if is older or have supporting pages to their products or referral links?. There are many reasons why your competitor is outperforming your product pages, perhaps receiving a duplicate and thin content warning message in the search Console is a good enough reason to be demoted.

I know that it will be a lot of work at this point trying to create content for all your products pages. You need to provide data and content that is meaningful for your intended or targeted audience. If the audience is too broad, You can star by grouping your products in a more meaningful way, group them together in categories with lots of content. Start by providing a central topic supported by the categories. Then, display more product related data that will help  differentiate your pages such as SKUs, inventory levels, number of purchases, products tags and any other piece of data that will require editing just a few lines of code. Wait a few weeks and start adding more content to the best performing pages. Also, make sure your meta tags are not globally set, to avoid meta data to be duplicated as well.

I highly recommend watching [this Video about thin content](https://youtu.be/w3-obcXkyA4)